# Is there an IOTA PHP library?

Tags: iri-legacy-api

How can I implement IOTA in my website in a way people can't see the code (contrary of javascript)? Each user would have an seed, how can I handle this sensitive information using IRI API?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one as yet ([full list](https://github.com/iotaledger)), although it would be easy to implement using the [javascript library](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js) as a guide. It's a series of API calls and responses.